# Dynamic tabs with Bootstrap, in PHP and MySQL

Tags: html, jquery

I've been trying to create a menu page on the website.
I fetched the contents of products and their categories using Bootstrap, PHP and MySQL.
The linking is not happening between the products and category.
At a time only the active class category with the product should be displayed but all products are getting display at the same time.

**PHP**

```php
<?php
include("config/config.php");

$category_sql  = "SELECT * FROM foodcategory";
$result        = mysqli_query($con, $category_sql);
$active_class  = 0;
$category_html = '';
$product_html  = '';

while ($category = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $current_tab     = '';
    $current_content = '';
    if (!$active_class) {
        $active_class    = 1;
        $current_tab     = 'active';
        $current_content = 'in active';

    }

    $category_html .= '<li class = "' . $current_tab . '"><a href = "#' . $category['catid'] . '" data-toggle = "tab">' . $category['catname'] . '</a></li>';
    $product_html .= '<div id = "' . $category['catid'] . '" class = "tab-pane fade" ' . $current_content . '>';

    $product_sql    = "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE catid = " . $category["catid"];
    $product_result = mysqli_query($con, $product_sql);

    if (!mysqli_num_rows($product_result)) {
        $product_html .= "<br>No products found!";
    }

    while ($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($product_result)) {
        $product_html .= '<div class="col-md-3 product">';
        $product_html .= '<div class="card mx-0 mb-4">';
        $product_html .= '<div class="card-header">' . $product['foodname'] . '</div>';
        $product_html .= '<div class="card-body"><p>' . $product['descr'] . '</p>';
        $product_html .= '<p>₹' . $product['foodprice'] . '</p></div>';
        $product_html .= '<input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name' . $product['foodid'] . '" value="' . $product['foodname'] . '">';
        $product_html .= '<input type="hidden" name="hidden_id"   id="id' . $product['foodid'] . '" value="' . $product['foodid'] . '">         <!--HIDDEN ID-->';
        $product_html .= '<input type="hidden" name="hidden_price"   id="price' . $product['foodid'] . '" value="' . $product['foodprice'] . '">     <!--HIDDEN PRICE-->';
        $product_html .= '<input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity"   id="quantity' . $product['foodid'] . '" value="1">     <!--HIDDEN PRICE-->';

        $product_html .= '<div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">';
        $product_html .= '<input type="button" class="add_to_cart btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" name="add_to_cart" id="' . $product['foodid'] . '" value="Add">';
        $product_html .= '</div>';

        $product_html .= '</div>';
        $product_html .= '</div>';
        $product_html .= '</div>';
    }
    $product_html .= '<div class = "clear_both"></div></div>';

}
?>
```

**HTML**

```html
<main class="my-4">
    <div class=c ontainer>
        <?php include_once("tabs.php"); ?>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <?php echo $category_html;?>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <?php echo $product_html;?>
            </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="nav-pills " id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
                        <?//php echo $tab_menu;?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
                        <?php //echo $tab_content;?>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div> -->
</main>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULFag.jpg)

The product is not getting linked with the specific category.
Everything is getting displayed on the screen.
What is the error here?

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">maincourse</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">pizza</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">southindian</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#4" data-toggle="tab">mc donalds</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#11" data-toggle="tab">burgers</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#12" data-toggle="tab">italian</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#13" data-toggle="tab">chinese</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#15" data-toggle="tab">desserts</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#17" data-toggle="tab">beverages</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="1" class="tab-pane fade" in active>
    <div class="col-md-3 product">
      <div class="card mx-0 mb-4">
        <div class="card-header">pav bhaji</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p>*Description to be added here*</p>
          <p>₹120</p>
        </div><input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name1" value="pav bhaji"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="id1" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price1" value="120"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity" id="quantity1"
          value="1">
        <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"><input type="button" class="add_to_cart btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" name="add_to_cart" id="1" value="Add"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 product">
    <div class="card mx-0 mb-4">
      <div class="card-header">paneer masala</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>*Description to be added here*</p>
        <p>₹100</p>
      </div><input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name2" value="paneer masala"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="id2" value="2"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price2" value="100"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity" id="quantity2"
        value="1">
      <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"><input type="button" class="add_to_cart btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" name="add_to_cart" id="2" value="Add"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 product">
  <div class="card mx-0 mb-4">
    <div class="card-header">aloo paratha</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>*Description to be added here*</p>
      <p>₹90</p>
    </div><input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name3" value="aloo paratha"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="id3" value="3"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price3" value="90"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity" id="quantity3"
      value="1">
    <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"><input type="button" class="add_to_cart btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" name="add_to_cart" id="3" value="Add"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 product">
  <div class="card mx-0 mb-4">
    <div class="card-header">butter sada dosa</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>*Description to be added here*</p>
      <p>₹80</p>
    </div><input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name4" value="butter sada dosa"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="id4" value="4"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price4" value="80"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity" id="quantity4"
      value="1">
    <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"><input type="button" class="add_to_cart btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" name="add_to_cart" id="4" value="Add"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 product">
  <div class="card mx-0 mb-4">
    <div class="card-header">farm house pizza</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>*Description to be added here*</p>
      <p>₹210</p>
    </div><input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name7" value="farm house pizza"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="id7" value="7"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price7" value="210"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity" id="quantity7"
      value="1">
    <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"><input type="button" class="add_to_cart btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" name="add_to_cart" id="7" value="Add"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 product">
  <div class="card mx-0 mb-4">
    <div class="card-header">chole bhature</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>gfvdc</p>
      <p>₹150</p>
    </div><input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name12" value="chole bhature"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="id12" value="12"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price12" value="150"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity" id="quantity12"
      value="1">
    <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"><input type="button" class="add_to_cart btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" name="add_to_cart" id="12" value="Add"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 product">
  <div class="card mx-0 mb-4">
    <div class="card-header">paneer makhani</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>gvcxgb</p>
      <p>₹110</p>
    </div><input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name13" value="paneer makhani"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="id13" value="13"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price13" value="110"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity" id="quantity13"
      value="1">
    <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"><input type="button" class="add_to_cart btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" name="add_to_cart" id="13" value="Add"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 product">
  <div class="card mx-0 mb-4">
    <div class="card-header">veg biryani</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>gbfvcx</p>
      <p>₹130</p>
    </div><input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name14" value="veg biryani"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="id14" value="14"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price14" value="130"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity" id="quantity14"
      value="1">
    <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"><input type="button" class="add_to_cart btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" name="add_to_cart" id="14" value="Add"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 product">
  <div class="card mx-0 mb-4">
    <div class="card-header">paneer kadhai</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>opiuyt</p>
      <p>₹110</p>
    </div><input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name15" value="paneer kadhai"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="id15" value="15"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price15" value="110"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity" id="quantity15"
      value="1">
    <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"><input type="button" class="add_to_cart btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" name="add_to_cart" id="15" value="Add"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 product">
  <div class="card mx-0 mb-4">
    <div class="card-header">c</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>d</p>
      <p>₹3</p>
    </div><input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name24" value="c"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="id24" value="24"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price24" value="3"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity" id="quantity24" value="1">
    <div
      class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"><input type="button" class="add_to_cart btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" name="add_to_cart" id="24" value="Add"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear_both"></div>
</div>
<div id="2" class="tab-pane fade">
  <div class="col-md-3 product">
    <div class="card mx-0 mb-4">
      <div class="card-header">cheese burst pizza</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>*Description to be added here*</p>
        <p>₹250</p>
      </div><input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name8" value="cheese burst pizza"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="id8" value="8"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price8" value="250"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity" id="quantity8"
        value="1">
      <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"><input type="button" class="add_to_cart btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" name="add_to_cart" id="8" value="Add"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 product">
  <div class="card mx-0 mb-4">
    <div class="card-header">burger pizza</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>*Description to be added here*</p>
      <p>₹120</p>
    </div><input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name9" value="burger pizza"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="id9" value="9"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price9" value="120"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity" id="quantity9"
      value="1">
    <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"><input type="button" class="add_to_cart btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" name="add_to_cart" id="9" value="Add"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 product">
  <div class="card mx-0 mb-4">
    <div class="card-header">double cheese pizza</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>*Description to be added here*</p>
      <p>₹300</p>
    </div><input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name19" value="double cheese pizza"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="id19" value="19"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price19" value="300"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity"
      id="quantity19" value="1">
    <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"><input type="button" class="add_to_cart btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" name="add_to_cart" id="19" value="Add"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear_both"></div>
</div>
<div id="3" class="tab-pane fade">
  <div class="col-md-3 product">
    <div class="card mx-0 mb-4">
      <div class="card-header">masala dosa</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>*Description to be added here*</p>
        <p>₹110</p>
      </div><input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name5" value="masala dosa"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="id5" value="5"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price5" value="110"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity" id="quantity5"
        value="1">
      <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"><input type="button" class="add_to_cart btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" name="add_to_cart" id="5" value="Add"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 product">
  <div class="card mx-0 mb-4">
    <div class="card-header">mysore masala dosa</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>iuyt</p>
      <p>₹120</p>
    </div><input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name6" value="mysore masala dosa"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="id6" value="6"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price6" value="120"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity" id="quantity6"
      value="1">
    <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"><input type="button" class="add_to_cart btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" name="add_to_cart" id="6" value="Add"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 product">
  <div class="card mx-0 mb-4">
    <div class="card-header">i</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>ijk</p>
      <p>₹6</p>
    </div><input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name22" value="i"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="id22" value="22"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price22" value="6"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity" id="quantity22" value="1">
    <div
      class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"><input type="button" class="add_to_cart btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" name="add_to_cart" id="22" value="Add"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear_both"></div>
</div>
<div id="4" class="tab-pane fade">
  <div class="col-md-3 product">
    <div class="card mx-0 mb-4">
      <div class="card-header">aloo tikki meal</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <p>qwerthy</p>
        <p>₹120</p>
      </div><input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name10" value="aloo tikki meal"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="id10" value="10"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price10" value="120"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity"
        id="quantity10" value="1">
      <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"><input type="button" class="add_to_cart btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" name="add_to_cart" id="10" value="Add"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 product">
  <div class="card mx-0 mb-4">
    <div class="card-header">mc veggie meal</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>fghjg</p>
      <p>₹150</p>
    </div><input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name11" value="mc veggie meal"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="id11" value="11"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price11" value="150"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity" id="quantity11"
      value="1">
    <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"><input type="button" class="add_to_cart btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" name="add_to_cart" id="11" value="Add"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 product">
  <div class="card mx-0 mb-4">
    <div class="card-header">o</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>ohj</p>
      <p>₹9</p>
    </div><input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" id="name23" value="o"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="id23" value="23"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" id="price23" value="9"><input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity" id="quantity23" value="1">
    <div
      class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between"><input type="button" class="add_to_cart btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" name="add_to_cart" id="23" value="Add"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear_both"></div>
</div>
<div id="11" class="tab-pane fade"><br>No products found!
  <div class="clear_both"></div>
</div>
<div id="12" class="tab-pane fade"><br>No products found!
  <div class="clear_both"></div>
</div>
<div id="13" class="tab-pane fade"><br>No products found!
  <div class="clear_both"></div>
</div>
<div id="15" class="tab-pane fade"><br>No products found!
  <div class="clear_both"></div>
</div>
<div id="17" class="tab-pane fade"><br>No products found!
  <div class="clear_both"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: my immediate thought goes to the first line of your php - you're selecting all from the foodcategory.. (btw, can you post the generated source html instead of the code containing html? Thanks.

Comment: The generated html source is getting printed in one line.                                             <li class = "active"><a href = "#1" data-toggle = "tab">maincourse</a></li><li class = ""><a href = "#2" data-toggle = "tab">pizza</a></li>                                                 
 <div id = "1" class = "tab-pane fade" in active>                                                        <div class="col-md-3 product"><div class="card mx-0 mb-4"><div class="card-header">pav bhaji</div>

Comment: that's not a complete section of code? Pls edit your question and post from the div container (with opening uls) to a closing div. Code pasted as comment lacks ul tags and closing div tags

Comment: Yes did. Please check.

Comment: @YojanaBakvar I was referring to the code you posted in the comments.

Comment: Since the size was huge it wasn't accepting. That's why edited the question and now you can see in the code snippet